how do i fix this kind of error, unboundLocalError
def address():
    inputName = input("Enter Name: ") 
    inputAddress = input("Enter address: ")
    return inputName
    return inputAddress
def nextPerson():
    next = input("Next Person to register? type Yes or No: ")
    if next == "yes":
        address = inputAddress()
        name = inputName()
nextPerson()
    else:
        pass

this should get the user inputs name and address and display inputs. if the user types yes,             should go back to the input address and name

In address, you have one return statement followed by a second return statement.  Since the first return will immediately exit the function, the second return can never be reached and is dead code.  Also, in nextPerson, your recursive call isn't indented, so is not part of the runction.  And else: pass doesn't really do anything.  Try to put together a [mre] that demonstrates the problem.

Your error is coming from nextPerson.  You're trying to call inputAddress and inputName as functions, but you never defined them.  They're local variables from your address function.  So not in scope, and not functions.

return inputAddress will never be executed. You are shadowing next. The functions inputAddress() and inputName() do not exist. You have multiple syntax errors. Try: Getting started
